# Eclipse load data from 2.3 to 4.4 every time you open an xml file

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently, I updated Eclipse with 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357. I don't know whether it's  a bug or a problem in my settings, the **Eclipse loads data from 2.3 to 4.4** every time you **open an XML file** and  when you press the `Save all` button. Due to this it is too slow to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also faced this issue, but Latest Updated ADT is now available, and you can check the updates [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

It seems to be fixed.

Comment: Yes it is fixed in 22.6.2.And is now avilable

Comment: It returned back in ADT (23.xx)

Comment: @AymanMahgoub I've used **ADT 23.0.0**, I've updated the **ADT** to the latest version **23.0.3**. But I didn't find any similar issues, i.e. *Eclipse loads data from x.x to x.x*.

Comment: I think the reason for loading all Android SDKs at XML every time I make an action, is using a large number of external libraries for my project and each one is using a different version of Android SDK, so  all libraries should use limited SDKs version to avoid such behavior.

Answer (score 8):

If you have multiple android projects in eclipse with different Project Build Target or when you change the build target to a new target , Eclipse will always try to load the graphical layout for that particular target version hence increasing the load time.

What I suggest is that you disable the "Build Automatically" option under "Project" atleast you should not experience the load time while saving.

Comment: What you said is acceptable but it does not solve the thing is i have never seen it loading when you open an layout in previous versions.It is very frustrating that you open a layout xml file and wait 2min to load. Are you facing any similar experience with recent updates?

Comment: I faced the same problem after 22.6.xx update, now eclipse is become very slow in load data. My impression is that Eclipse load data from Android 2.3 to 4.4 also before this update, but now the loading is very very slow. I disable "Build Automatically", otherwise it is impossible to work.

Comment: I have this issue from 22.6 as well... very very frustrating

Comment: Same problem here! It just loads every installed SDK over and over again – for every android resource file. Really frustrating…

Comment: I have it as well. how can i downgrade?!

Comment: Yes @vicky , I too face the same issue but only for the 1st time on start of eclipse,like if already data is loaded, eclipse wont try to load data again when opening XML files until I restart eclipse or the change the target version.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is still not fixed with the 22.6.1 SDK release (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67084) but should be fixed with the 22.6.2 SDK release.

I specifically checked for this issue in the SDK changelog.

Comment: I got the same response in "https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67249"

Comment: Returned back at ADT (23.xx)